# How can I submit a batch job knitting an Rscript on LSF?

Tags: r, bash, cluster-computing, r-markdown

How to knit an Rmd document in a job on an LSF cluster?

I tried this:

```
bsub -q normal -E 'test -e /nfs/users/nfs_c/username' -R "select[mem>20000] rusage[mem=20000]" -M20000 -o DOWNLOAD.o -e DOWNLOAD.e -J DOWNLOAD Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('code/12downloadSeq.Rmd')"
```

The above command does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error in strsplit(version_info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
Execution halted
```

On the other hand, a script like the following to run a normal R script works:

```
bsub -q normal -E 'test -e /nfs/users/nfs_c/cr7' -R "select[mem>20000] rusage[mem=20000]" -M20000 -o RSCRIPT.o -e RSCRIPT.e -J RSCRIPT Rscript code/setup.R
```

I imagine there is a problem with the quotation marks but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: I think the problem comes from Pandoc is not found by rmarkdown

Comment: run a simple R script with `rmarkdown::pandoc_available() `. I bet you will get `FALSE`.

Comment: rmarkdown::pandoc_available() returns TRUE

Comment: Very strange. What do you get when you run an R script with `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`?

Comment: Please, could you also run in an R script `rmarkdown:::find_program("pandoc")`?

Comment: Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC") returns an empty string.

Comment: rmarkdown:::find_program("pandoc") returns "/software/.../apps/usr/bin/pandoc"

Comment: after installing pandoc with conda, rmarkdown:::find_program("pandoc") just returns a different path to a pandoc installation:
"/lustre/.../output/software/anaconda3/envs/phd/bin/pandoc"

Comment: Try in your very first script: ```Rscript -e "Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = rmarkdown:::find_program('pandoc')); rmarkdown::render('code/12downloadSeq.Rmd')"```